# Creating a filter with a column that has multiple values with a delimiter in tableau

Tags: filter, tableau-api

I have data like

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4  
Alpha   DepA    1       A;B;C  
Beta    DepB    2       A;B  
Chi     DepC    3       C
```

So, I want to use Col4 as a filter with A,B,C as values and whenever I select A from filter it should display rows that contain Col4 value A(Here first two rows should be the output),
if I select A,B in the filter output should be first two rows as they contain A and B.
if I select C as a filter then first and third rows should be output as they contain C in Col4.

Filter should be list with checkboxes
Col4
A
B
C

so that I can select multiple values or a single value.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a parameter and filter based on that.  Create a parameter and manually enter your list of A, B, C as pictured below.
[image]

Then create a filter with a formula condition as pictured below.
[image]

After you have these built, just right click on your parameter and 'Show Parameter Control'

Comment: OP wanted to select multiple values at a time and with this approach it would not be feasible... right?